# Rotating Frames of Reference: Doubt while deriving the velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames

I am following an [online Chapter](http://muenchow.cms.udel.edu/html/classes/gfd/book/IntroGFDChapt2.pdf) on Coriolis force, where the author develops the equations for a rotating frame of reference. The Figure and most of the notation used in the derivation can be understood from the diagram shown below:

[image]

The $x$ and $y$ coordinates (in the rotating frame) are related to the $X$ and $Y$ (in the fixed frame) by the following equations:

[image]

Taking the time derivative we get:

[image]

Now, I have the following questions based on $dx\over{dt}$ and $dy\over{dt}$

1) What do these quantities represent? Are they the components of velocity of a particle observed from the rotating frame of reference?

2) If we further simply the expressions for $dx\over{dt}$ and $dy\over{dt}$, we can write:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dX}{dt}\cos(\Omega t)+\frac{dY}{dt}\sin(\Omega t)+\Omega y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{dX}{dt}\sin(\Omega t)+\frac{dY}{dt}\sin(\Omega t)-\Omega x$$

Is there any significance of the last terms?

Answer (score 1):

> What do these quantities represent? Are they the components of velocity of a particle observed from the rotating frame of reference?

$\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are indeed the components of the velocity of the particle observed from the rotating frame.

> Is there any significance of the last terms?

Yes, indeed it has.

---

The vectorial relation

$$\mathrm d\mathbf A_\mathrm S~=~ \mathrm d\mathbf A_\mathrm{S'} + (\omega \times \mathbf A)~\mathrm dt \tag 1$$

shows how the differential of $\mathbf A$ as observed from an inertial frame $\rm S$ is related to the differential of the same observed from a rotating-frame $\rm S'$; the rightmost term connects the two or more accurately *transforms* the change as viewed from $\rm S'$ to the change as viewed from $\rm S\,.$

$(\omega\times \mathbf A)\,\mathrm dt$ is the *rotating effect* due to the change of the unit vectors of $\rm S'$ over the course of time due to its rotation and it must be added to the change exhibited in the non-inertial frame to get the *actual* change.

$(1)$ is a very powerful relation as $\bf A$ can be 'any vector as you please'.

At the present context, let we choose $\bf A$ to be the position vector $\mathbf r\;;$ then $(1)$ infers

$$\mathbf v~=~ \mathbf v' +  \underbrace{\mathbf \omega\times \mathbf r}_{\textrm{velocity of the coordinate system}~~ \mathrm S'} \;.$$

It can now be easily decomposed to the components that OP wrote.

Comment: $(1)$ is a very powerful relation as $A$ can be 'any vector as you please'.- The author of my textbook calls it an 'operator equation,' I found this rather abrupt as I was reading the book. I am wondering if you could further justify (possibly prove) why any vector can be fitted into $(1)$. Anyways, thank you for your answer.

Comment: That's how _vectors_ are transformed :)

Answer (score 0):

The last term seems to be the effect of the addition of tangential velocity component $\vec\omega\times \vec r$. 

$\vec r = x \hat x + y \hat y$

$\vec\omega = \omega \hat z$

$\vec\omega\times \vec r = \omega x \hat z \times \hat x +\omega y\hat z\times \hat y = \omega x\hat y-\omega y\hat x$

But since it's the rotating frame that is rotating with rate $\omega$ and not the object in the rotating frame, subtracting $\vec\omega\times \vec r$ will make up for the effect of the rotation.

Hence the velocity correction with respect to x-coordinate is $\omega y\hat x$ and the velocity correction for the y-coordinate is $-\omega x\hat y$